# Understanding the bestowment and receiving the greatest good (HaShem Himself)?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, parashat-bereishit, commentaries, ramchal

The Ramchal, in short, teaches (Derech HaShem) that HaShem is absolutely, completely and perfectly good; His essence/nature so to speak is the totality of goodness. Because of this He wanted to bestow the greatest good possible. Anything less would simply not be good enough (the greatest good). But what is the greatest good? What is the ultimate good that God can bestow on His creation? The ultimate good is HaShem Himself. The greatest good that He can bestow is Himself.

So here's my question:
HaShem can't give Himself literally: like when I give something to the other in order to receive it and becoming the owner of it. So how do I need to understand this, ***what's the meaning of HaShem wanted to bestow Himself (the greatest good possible)*** and ***how does one receive if it's not literally?***

Comment: You're forgetting that the greatest good is one that is EARNED and not GIVEN. We EARN a relationship with HASHEM, and thereby the greatest good, through our independent actions in Olam Hazeh.

Answer (score 1):

Hashem gives from Himself literally, just not totally. It is obviously impossible to grasp Hashem, but He does shine His glory. When someone is able to connect to Hashem, He is bestowing Himself in whatever amount. The Rambam says that perception of Hashem is the greatest enjoyment. This is what the Gemara refers to when it describes in [Taanis 31](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%90) how the Tzaddikim will be able to point to Hashem.

Answer (score 0):

Once heard in a lecture by Rabbi Becher: The idea is to make yourself into a receptacle capable of receiving/appreciating His goodness.

Comment: Which Rabbi Becher? I'm not sure this answers the first part of the question:  "*what's the meaning of [...]*".

Answer (score 0):

Humans being **for** G-d is the greatest good. To understand to the best of your ability G-d and his wisdom, and by making everything you do be for the sake of heaven, you become a perfect human being. A perfect chair is the chair that best serves the needs your back and tuchas, and its entire existence is aimed at serving you. Anything about the chair that isn't about making you happy is either superfluous or detrimental. Loosing it would be an improvement. A perfect human on the other hand, lives it's entire existence for the sake of heaven. Any urges, thoughts, or actions that isn't for the sake of heaven is either vain or sinful, or both depending on the severity. The better the person, the less they exist in this way.